# Hibernate spends a lot of time for connection to the database

Tags: performance, hibernate, jpa, database-connection

I connect my application to DB and Hibernate spends a lot of time for connection to the database.
How can I configure `persistence` for remote db connection.
Here is my persistence.xml

```
<properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/temp"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="user03022016"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
```

here is my function, which call connection and  where i send query

```
public List<Posts> connect() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        EntityManager em=EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        Query q=em.createQuery("Select p from Posts p");
        result=q.getResultList();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You don't seem to have a question, or have done much to debug the "problem" (whatever it is). You have a log which tells you what is happening and no reference is made to it. You don't seem to ever close EntityManager. "a lot of time" ... is very descriptive

Comment: Are you getting a timeout error

Comment: @ingrid, no but it spends about 4-5 seconds for connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configured an external connection pool or are you using the built-in one? If you are using the built-in one, this could explain why it spends 4 seconds at obtaining a connection as in the worst case a new one has to be created which is expensive.

Maybe try to configure an external connection pool as described here:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch01.html

Answer (score 0):

To speed up thing a bit in general change hibernate.show_sql and hibernate.format_sql to false. For connection simply put this property:

```
<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_default" value="false"/>
```

This will make your session build faster.